# How do I make a virtualised WAN?

Tags: linux, virtualization, port-forwarding, wan

I want to create a virtualised WAN. As in, I want to have a couple of VMs (VBox) on one physical host machine, that exist on separate LANs, but that can talk to each other. Do I make the VMs, set them up with different IP addresses (e.g. 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8) and then configure port forwarding between them somehow???

I've seen articles that set up port forwarding on port 2222, but I don't really understand why this works. How is setting up the VM to listen to port 2222 and then port forward from there to, say, port 80, any different from just telling the VM to listen on port 80 in the first place?

FYI, the VMs run Ubuntu Desktop 14.x.

Comment: If the VMs are all on one physical host, as your question implies, why not create a host-only network between the VMs?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I thought stack exchange would email me when replies came in! As for why I'm not doing it as an internal network - I need to demonstrate understanding of WAN technology :) I would prefer to do it with physical kit, but lack the infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a good exercise and can easily be achieved.  A simple setup could include 3 virtual machines, which would mimic a typical workstation that would access a server on the internet through a gateway/router.

I would setup two separate internal networks (VM network adapter set to "Internal Network"), one called `lan` representing the LAN and one called `public` representing the "public internet", or in this case the server the workstation is trying to reach.

The three VMs would be:

1. Workstation (connected to LAN only)
2. Router (connected to both LAN & Public)
3. Server (connected to Public only)

I would recommend running something like [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) on the router VM, since it is designed to function as a router and is already configured to do so, but you could do it with a regular Linux machine (but that is beyond the scope of this question).

You will have to setup static IPs (say in the `10.0.0.10` for the router and `10.0.0.20` for the server) on the public network.  If you're running pfSense, you'll have to configure a static IP (say `192.168.0.1`) for it on the LAN side, but it can handle assigning an address to the workstation via DHCP.

[image: Network Diagram]

Once everything is configured and has the right IP, you should be able to setup access the server from the workstation by its IP.  If the server wants to contact the workstation, you would need to setup port forwarding in the router.

If you want to get a bit more complicated, you could add in another router and workstation so you have two separate LANs connected to a public network.  In this case both workstations can communicate directly with the server, however if the workstations want to communicate directly with each other port forwarding will need to be setup to in at least one of the routers.

[image: Network Diagram]

Comment: Thansks for the detailed answer! More than I could have hoped for. I would upvote you but apparently I'm too new here to do that just yet. Thanks again!