# Network between three guest OS on linux

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ping

I need to create a network between three guest OS (ubuntu), one of them have to be smth like router between two others. See scheme below:

[A] eth0(ip 1.1.1.1)-->(net1)<--eth0(ip 1.1.1.2) [B] eth1(ip 2.2.2.2)--->(net2)<----eth0(ip 2.2.2.1) [C]

The problem is that after creating three guest OS's, setting static ip, I can from virt A ping 1.1.1.2 and 2.2.2.2, from B ping all ips, from C can ping 1.1.1.2 and 2.2.2.2. But I can't ping C from A, and A from C. How I can do that?

Comment: Related question [here](http://superuser.com/a/766963/820).  But, it comes down to you need to have your `[B]` VM setup as a router.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not phrased very clearly.
System B can ping A and C because it has two NICs, one on each network [1.x.x.x and 2.x.x.x]
If you make 2.2.2.2 the default gateway for system c, and if 1.1.1.2 is the default gateway for system A, you need a route in system B to transverse networks.

What i'm getting at, is normally (IME) dual NICs act completely independently unless you expressly set the system up as a router, allowing data to come in one and out another. This would be done with iptables.

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/48438-configuring-your-linux-server-as-a-router/